# Whatsapp Message from the website showing Plus Sign

Tags: php, whatsapp

I have a form as shown below it redirects to api.whatsapp.com on submit. With Text message as Some+Text+Message and messages as plus sign between text spaces.

How to remove plus signs between words in the message?

```
<div class="weakly_block whatsapp contactwhatsapp">
        <h5><span style="padding-left:20px"></span>Whatsapp Us</h5> 
            <div class="new_letr new_letr2">
            <form target="_blank" method="get" action="https://api.whatsapp.com/send" >
            <input name="phone" value="919990009998" type="hidden">
            <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type a message" class="pass_input" style="opacity:0">
            <button type="submit" class="subscribe_btn" style="opacity:0">Submit</button>
            </form>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: How to change it in the url params. which is already submitted

Comment: _“How to remove plus signs between words in the message?”_ - you don’t - not using this simple setup. All you are doing here is submit a form - and in that case, you can not control how the parameters are added to the URL, this is done by the default form submission algorithm, and URL-encoding is handled by the browser. You can either send this to a server-side script of your own first, that assembles the target URL in the correct form and then redirects there, or you can read the values using JavaScript, assemble the URL, and then use window.open or location.href to get there.